# Tab items container offset and fixed width

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Is it possible to make an offset header container (container with TabItems), for placing elements in a line and set fixed width to this container for placing elements after with a standard TabControl? And smooth scrolling for TabItems (default WM_HSCROLL moving it sharply)?

[image]

Comment: no that is not possible without writing it yourself - sorry.

Comment: If you're going to make your own, it's not a easy task.  You have to account for resizing of the window, resizing of the tabs when tabs get numerous and addition/deletion of tabs, etc.  It's actually a small project in itself.  This is mine after a lot of work: http://i.imgur.com/LC9IyYR.png